# Orbeon: success uri configuration

Tags: orbeon

I want to set success uri to Another Orbeon form.
Example:
After clicking on Workflow send Button, it should redirects to new Orbeon form

I have tried with

```
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"
    value="/fr/MY-app-name/My-form-name/new"/>
```

It seems it is calling this page after clicking send button, but it is **Not showing any control of this form**

I have also set this property:

```
<property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.prune.*.*"
    value="false"/>
```

Comment: Which version of Orbeon Forms? Starting 4.2 this has become much more flexible.

Comment: I am using 4.1.0. So you mean this will work for 4.2 ?

Comment: Do you want to send the XML data to the 2nd form, or just navigate to the 2nd form?

Comment: I just want to navigate to second form.

Comment: The easy setting is only available starting 4.3, unfortunately. Are you able to upgrade? There you can write a simple process like `send then navigate(uri = '/my/other/form')`.